# Positioning a UIImageView using Pixate Freestyle

Tags: ios, pixate

I'm trying to move a UIImageView as a test to see if Pixate is fit for purpose with what i'm working on but i'm not clued up on CSS albeit it seems straight forward enough from the pixate documentation.

So i have a simple UIImageView on the right of my view and want to move it to the left it's really that simple.

```
.smallCellSmallImage {
position : 10px 10px;
background-image : url(pixateImageChannel2.png);
}
```

This is loading in my test image fine but nothing happens with the position property.
Can anyone with Pixate or CSS knowledge tell me what i'm missing.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position` is not supported, use `top:` `left:` `width:` and `height:`. `size:` is also supported. Note, that position and size is ignored by iOS when using auto-layout (which is enabled on iOS 7 by default).